# simultaneously download on server and on user

Tags: php, header, download

I am currently developing an application in PHP in which my server (a dedicated server) must to download a file, and the user should download the file in same time.

Here is an example :

- Server start to download a file at a time *A*.
- User wants to download this file at the time *A* + 3 seconds (for example)

I already solved the problem :"*If the user downloads the file faster than the server..*". But I didn't know how to make a php script in which the user is gonna to download the full file (it means that the size must be the full size of the file, not the size it's currently downloaded at the time A+3seconds). I already make that :

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$data['name'].'";'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Content-Length: '.$data['size']);
readfile($remoteFile);
```

But it doesn't work, the user is gonna download just the size it is currently on the server (which corrupt the file) and not the full file...

If you have any solution, thank you.

Comment: does it work if you leave out the length? and why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: What the... The server serving the file must also "download" it as fast as the client does, is that it?

Comment: What are you using on the server to download the file? CURL? `fread`?

Comment: Currently, I just use the copy(); function of php. I thought that I didn't need more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably pipe the file manually, by opening the connection and reading until you're past all headers. Then once you've figured out the `Content-Length`, send that to the user and just `echo` all remaining data you get (do use `flush()` and avoid output buffers).

Pseudocode(-ish):

```
open the file
# grab headers
while you didn't get all HTTP headers:
    read more
look for the Content-Length header
send the Content-Length header

# grab the file
while the rest of the request isn't done
    read more
    send it to the user
    flush the buffers

done
```

Comment: I don't have to send the Content-Length header no ? I already know the full size of the file. And if I try this algorithm, I must to wait that the server finish to download the file no ?

Comment: That's the point of my "algorithm", it doesn't require you to finish the download. You basically look for the server's Content-Length header and send it, and *then* you start sending the rest of the file.

Comment: And in that case, the user should not leave the website, no ? How can I send the data to the user in order to allow the user to download, the file ? In my tests, the content of the file is written on the site and not send as a download to the user

Comment: In that case you're probably missing the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8466507/89771) answer, you can use cURL to greatly simplify the algorithm by using the `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` callbacks - see [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Answer (score -1):

Don't send the content-length header. It's not required assuming you're using http 1.1(your webserver almost certainly does). Drawback is their browser cant show download time/size remaining.

Comment: I can't, if I don't send the content-length header, the downloaded file will not have the full size. I precise that $data['size'] contains the full size of the file.